# Pagination Not Working With filter. Click page 2(with filter) will return to Page 2 with no filter

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, append, laravel-pagination

I have problem with pagination. while using it with filter, only the first page is working.

**Controller**

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::where(function($query) {
        //  filter category
        $category = Input::has('category')
            ? Input::get('category')
            : ['Clothes','Pants','Equipments','Shoes','Gears'];

        if (isset($category)) {
            $query->whereIn('category',$category);
        }

        // filter price
        $min_price = Input::has('min_price') ? Input::get('min_price') : 1 ;
        $max_price = Input::has('max_price') ? Input::get('max_price') : 999 ;
        if (isset($min_price) && isset($max_price)) {
            $query->where('price','>=',$min_price)
                ->where('price','<=',$max_price);
        }

        // filter brand
        $brand = Input::has('brand')
            ? Input::get('brand')
            : ['Adidas','Nike','Puma','Mizuno','Umbro','Line 7'];

        if (isset($brand)) {
            $query->whereIn('brand',$brand);
        }

        // filter store
        $store = Input::has('store')
            ? Input::get('store')
            : ['JD Sports Malaysia','SportsClick','Al-Ikhsan','Sports Wear','Sports Direct'];

        if (isset($store)) {
            $query->whereIn('store',$store);
        }

        //filter Gender
        $gender = Input::has('gender') 
            ? Input::get('gender') 
            : ['Male','Female','None'];

        if(isset($gender)){
            $query->whereIn('gender',$gender);
        }

        $search = Input::get('query');

        if (isset($search)) {
            $query->where('product','like',"%$search%")
                ->orWhere('brand', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('category', 'like', "%$search%")->get();
        }
    })->paginate(12);

    return view('customer.category',compact('products'))->withProduct($products);
}
```

**Blade**

```
<!-- store bottom filter -->
<div class="store-filter clearfix mt-5">
    <span class="store-qty">Showing {{$products->count()}} Result(s)</span>
        <ul class="store-pagination" 
            {!! $products->links();!!}  
        </ul> 
    </div>
<!-- /store bottom filter -->
```

The controller code is how I get the filter input

and the view is how I display the pagination link

the page for number 2 and above should display the filtered product

Comment: It seems your pagination links are not keeping the query parameters, that is why you are not getting the filtered result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$products->links();` to  `$products->appends($_GET)->links()`, I think you will get the query parameters added in links.